# Display table ordered by row and columns

Tags: python, html, arrays, django

I am struggling to display an HTML table with data issued from a database.
I just retrieve the data using a SELECT and Join multiples tables.
Datas are retrieved like :

| StorageLocation | Quantity | RiskPhrase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage1 | 10 | H225 |
| Storage2 | 4 | H225 |
| Storage1 | 3 | H226 |
| Storage3 | 3 | H226 |
| Storage4 | 3 | H226 |
| Storage4 | 3 | H300 |

I want to be displayed like this :

| StorageLocation | H225 | H226 | H300 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Storage1 | 10 | 0 | 3 |
| Storage2 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Storage3 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Storage4 | 0 | 3 | 3 |

I really don't know how to deal with this.
Is Dataframe the best solution ?
Your help will be more than appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you have control over the query I suggest doing the sorting there. You might need a self join and an outer join to get what you are after.

Comment: Do you really want the H225 column listed twice in your output? I think your inputs don't match the output in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot("StorageLocation", "RiskPhrase", "Quantity").fillna(0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

                 H225  H226  H300
StorageLocation                  
Storage1         10.0   3.0   0.0
Storage2          4.0   0.0   0.0
Storage3          0.0   3.0   0.0
Storage4          0.0   3.0   3.0
```